# Prevent signups with Facebook proxy email

Tags: facebook

Problem is, when a user clicks on FB Login button on my site, Facebook API throws him with a window which ask for access permissions(which is the usual flow). But when the user chooses the proxy mail address (anonymous), then I want to force the user to login only using his real email id.

How am I supposed to handle this ?

I can detect that user used proxy email and prevent him from registering, but then I can't remove my app from his list of authorized apps - meaning I can't get him to that initial dialog for choosing which email he will provide.

Comment: Please update your question with a tag for the relevant programming language. Previously, this question was tagged with asp.net, php and ruby-on-rails.

Comment: I updated my original answer with some new found information which I think you might be able to take advantage of and will help you do exactly what you want to do.

Comment: The proxy mail system is there for a good reason - to prevent spam. Besides being able to spam/sell the user's real email address, what reason could you have for forcing the user to give another email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force the user to go through the authorization dialog again, because as far as Facebook is concerned, the user has installed your application and nothing else needs to happen.  The best thing you can do here is write your own form which informs the user that the Facebook proxy e-mail address is unacceptable and you need a real e-mail address.  Unfortunately, this does not force the user to give you their Facebook account e-mail address, or even a real e-mail address.  This is the best we have via Facebook though, and it's just something we have to deal with.

**UPDATE 5/10/11**

I was browsing around the Facebook documentation, and found a method that exists in the old *Legacy REST API* which actually allows you to remove extended permissions for your app from a user. I think you could use this exact API call to manage getting non-proxy addresses from your Facebook user, while still using the native install dialog.

I tested this using the FB JS SDK and it worked!  The method you need to use is the [`auth.revokeExtendedPermission`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeExtendedPermission/) method.  Here are 2 examples of calling that method via the JS SDK and the PHP SDK.

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
FB.api({
    method: 'auth.revokeExtendedPermission',
    perm:   'read_stream'
}, function(response)
{ 
    console.log(response) 
});
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'auth.revokeExtendedPermission',
'perm'   => 'email',
'uid'    => $uid
));
```

Because these use the *Legacy REST API* they're not as "supported" as the new Graph API.  I've not seen anything regarding migrating this feature to the Graph API.  Hopefully they will.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke revocation of the app through graph api (as below) with the php sdk then redirect user back through your dialog with this non-proxy requirement explained.

```
private function revokeAccess() {
    $access_token = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
    $result = $this->facebook->api(array(
        'method' => 'auth.revokeAuthorization',
        'uid' => $this->{facebook id here},
        'access_token' => $access_token
            ));
    return $result;
}
```

This code is php.
This completely removes the app.
Returns 1 on success; 0 on failure.
$this->facebook == facebook object from the facebook php sdk.